# All of a sudden the Maps in my Android Map stop working and all I see are a bunch of X's

Tags: android

I've deleted my debug key, generated a new one, gotten the new MD5 fingerprint and registered that with google and used the new API key in my layout XML, still broken. It was all working fine until a few days ago. Now all my maps are just a bunch of X's. Any ideas?

Do I need to sign my app for debug/development? All I have done so far is generate the fingerprint and used that to get an API key, am I missing a step perhaps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="edu.elon.ecs"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:debuggable="true">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <service android:name="NewsEvents_Service"></service>

        <activity android:name=".ECS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="ElonMap"></activity>
        <activity android:name="NavigationActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="NewsEvents"></activity>
        <activity android:name="EditKeywords"></activity>
        <activity android:name="FullNewsEvent"></activity>        
        <activity android:name="OnTheJob"></activity>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Looks weird.. does all your apps having maps are having this issue!?

Comment: This is my only one, but it was working two days ago.

Comment: If you are using the emulator, does the built in browser app still let you connect to any sites?

Comment: Not an emulator, on my DevPhone it does still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that your permissions are still OK? You need the INTERNET permission to download the map tiles.

I've also been bitten, by putting the `<uses-permission>` tag after the `<application>` tag. This worked on all devices I tried except the SE Xperia X10 mini. Putting `<uses-permission>` first solved that one.

Also, make sure that you actually have an internet connection on your device (can you load web pages, for instance?)

You should also make sure that your application is being signed using the same keystore you used to generate your map key. If you're using eclipse to build, you'll find that keystore in the preferences, under Windows > Preferences > Android > Build.

Comment: I do have the internet permission in the XML. What do you mean tag after tag?

Comment: Sorry, I was inserting xml tags directly in the answer, which got hidden. Updated the answer.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now, yes I have it before the application tag. I have also started a new project and inserted my code into this one to no avail. Do you know anything about hidden preferences in ADT that might be causing me trouble? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the answer again, with some info on how to check what keystore is being used to sign your app. Try checking that as well?

Comment: You don't get any interesting output from logcat when trying to load the map either?

Comment: I get this "Map Activity: Couldn't get connection factory client"

Comment: I think that is pretty standard error when the API key is off. Did you verify that the debug key bing used to sign your app is the same as the one you used for generating the key?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem on your mapView. are you trying to emulate satellite and street view?

Or your zoom level is too high.